# Mean Value Property of Harmonic Functions

Tags: analysis, partial-differential-equations, harmonic-functions

I can't prove this theorem:

"Let $\Omega$ is a bounded domain, $u\in C^2(\Omega)$ satisfy $\Delta u=0(\geq0,\leq0)$, then for any ball $B=B_R(y)\subset \subset \Omega$, we have

$$u(y)=(\leq,\geq)\frac{1}{n\omega_nR^{n-1}}\int_{\partial B}u\ ds$$

$$u(y)=(\leq,\geq)\frac{1}{\omega_nR^n}\int_{B}u\ dx$$

Thanks

Comment: This is a standard exercise using Green's formulas as well as a Green's function for the Laplacian.

Comment: I assume this is homework? Can you be more specific about your background and what you've learned in the course? You labeled this the mean value property of harmonic functions. That's (one part of) the first result. Then you would use polar coordinates to integrate it to get the second result.

Comment: If you want to try to write it up and ask questions about particular points you don't understand, I'll help. But I'm not going to take a half hour to type out a reasonably standard proof, no.

Comment: @TedShifrin I'm having trouble in differentiating with respect to r. Every proof I'm using as guide to understand uses that differentiating with respect to r equals the directional derivative of u with respect to the normal vector (like the second page of [this reference](https://web.math.ucsb.edu/~cmart07/Harmonic%20functions.pdf)). I don't understand why this is true.

Comment: You should probably post this as a separate question. Think about it this way. You can parametrize explicitly and write the boundary integral as $g(r)=\int_0^{2\pi} u(y+re^{i\theta})\,d\theta$. Now it's the standard formula for differentiating under the integral sign: $g'(r)=\int_0^{2\pi} \left(\frac{\partial}{\partial r} u(y+re^{i\theta}\right)d\theta$. Computing the radial change is the directional derivative in the direction normal to the circle, and this in turn is given by $\nabla u\cdot\mathbf n$. Write it out explicitly if you need to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a hint to get you started:

Define $A(r) = \int_{\partial B(y,r)} u(x) \, dx$, and show that $A(r)$ is constant by differentiating with respect to $r$, and showing that the derivative is zero by using the divergence theorem to replace the integrand with a $\Delta u$.

For the subharmonic and superharmonic cases, the same technique leads to $A(r)$ increasing and decreasing, respectively.

Comment: I'm having trouble in differentiating with respect to r. Every proof I'm using as guide to understand uses that differentiating with respect to r equals the directional derivative of u with respect to the normal vector (like the second page of [this reference](https://web.math.ucsb.edu/~cmart07/Harmonic%20functions.pdf)). I don't understand why this is true.